# SwiftUI tint image, Image from UIImage constructor -> lost of tint

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage

I struggle with SwiftUI Image and its tint color.
I use the Image Constructor from UIImage. Since UIImage have this method to tint that returns a new UIImage (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624153-withrenderingmode)

this is not working, when displayed, image keep being black/white, no tint color applied. for some reason, the Image constructor with uiimage, take the original image, and not the tinted one

Does any one came up with a solution ? or a clean workaround to keep the color applied on the UIImage ?
thank in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

class PlayGroundModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {}
}

struct PlayGround: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: PlayGroundModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let uiImage = UIImage(systemName: "cart")!
                .withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                .withTintColor(.blue)
            
            Image(uiImage: uiImage).resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
            Image(uiImage: uiImage).resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            
            let uiImage2 = uiImage
                .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                .withTintColor(UIColor.purple)
            
            Image(uiImage: uiImage2).resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
            Image(uiImage: uiImage2).resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        }
        
    }
}

struct PlayGround_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlayGround(model: PlayGroundModel())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: show your (full) code as text, not a picture of part of it.